# broken wordpress site on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, filezilla

I was attempting to learn how to use my server via FileZilla. FileZilla has a very sensitive drag and drop system, and I accidentally moved files from one file to another without noticing. Now my website is no longer functioning. I am not familiar with what a Wordpress site should look like on my server. Looking at the file list (see below), can anyone see what might be missing, or do they have any suggestions for what solutions I can check. My website (andelad.co.uk) is now simply blank. My other websites are working, so it seems that something is distinctly wrong with this one site.

Any help is useful, thanks all,

[My file list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNjqV.png)

Comment: I suppose that the index.php with a size of only 418 bytes is not as expected

Comment: Thank you, it seems we’re okay on the index page, but well spotted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the *wp-includes* folder. You must have dragged it inside *wp-admin* or *wp-content* folders.

Comment: Brilliant. Found it, and have moved it into the right place! It’s back online, but there are a few images missing (actually, quite a few!) The site is andelad.co.uk. This may be getting more complicated, but any ideas? Or ideas where I could learn where to check? I’m pretty sure it’s another drag and drop error somewhere.

Comment: Actually - thanks again. Found the issue. Thanks loads for your help.